# Getting error when installing theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newer in wordpress. I have following directory structure for wordpress

[image]

When I install theme using zip file like following
[image]

Then I am getting error like

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2014/07. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
> Is there any missing?

Comment: you are working on local or server ? If on server then, please check directory permission wp-content, is it writable or not ?

Comment: Local server and ubuntu OS

Comment: @Khushboo Thanks as per your feedback I got solution.

Comment: Downvoted please comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by following steps:

1. Created upload folder in wp-content
2. Give permission to `upload` folder like in step-3
3. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads

After performing this three step It's working fine. Thanks!